# How to enable struts2 convention plugin

Tags: struts2

The problem seems silly because I properly misunderstood the document. Basically I just want to run the hello-world actionless example according to this [instruction](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/convention-plugin.html) by simply adding hello.jsp file into ***WEB-INF/content*** and then running ***localhost:8080/test/hello***, but Struts keeps showing the exception ***java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport.index()***.

So I wonder there is any configuration need to be done before running. I couldn't find any thing about configuration for hello-world example.

Could anyone suggest me correct way ? Thanks

***Updated:*** here is  project tree, no action, no any fancy.

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── resources
        │   └── struts.xml
        └── webapp
            ├── WEB-INF
            │   ├── content
            │   │   └── hello.jsp
            │   └── web.xml
            └── index.jsp
```

The dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-rest-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: We'll need more information, like version, what specifically you're deploying (libs mostly), etc.

Comment: Generally if you have a working struts2 application... that is you have one working action. Then you should just need to add struts2-conventions-plugin-xxx.jar where xxx is the same version as struts2 core... If you are using maven struts2-core is a dependency of the plug-in so all you need to do is add the plug-in. After that there shouldn't need to be any configuration. Create the file /WEB-INF/content/hello.jsp and it should be accessible. Certain configuration could cause it to fail... Try using a package that does not exist such as /WEB-INF/content/xyz/hello.jsp

Comment: The last hello view would be access with localhost:8080/test/xyz/hello assuming your application is called test.

Comment: Still don't know what version of S2, what libraries you're deploying, what's in your config, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have mixed the Struts 2 Convention plugin with the Struts 2 REST plugin and that's why Struts 2 is looking for method called index() (default method for REST).

Remove the REST plugin - `struts2-rest-plugin` - and everything should work as expected.

If you want to mix Convention with REST consult the docs, eg. you can use `struts.rest.namespace` to distinguish REST part of the application from normal web application part.

**EDIT**

If you want to mix both parties - a normal web app and REST endpoints - you can consider using [PrefixBasedActionMapper](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-mapper.html#prefixbasedactionmapper) which allows use different mappers per url. Plus you should use `PrefixBasedActionProxyFactory` to use proper factories to construct actions that will match the url.